# Directive not being added in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension with background script. I'm injecting scripts and all of them are getting loaded correctly. I'm trying to create a sidebar with a logo and a sidebar div taking up full height and 300px of width. But the sidebar is loading up only, not the logo. Here's the manifest:

```
{
    "name": "My Ex-Tension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "A content sharing extension for chrome browsers",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": { "persistent": false, "scripts": [ "background.js" ] },
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "<all_urls>" ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [ "assets/css/style.css", "app/icon/*", "app/base/*" ]
}
```

All scripts are getting injected using background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    var scripts = [
        "pre-load.js", "assets/js/jquery.js", "assets/js/angular.js",
        "app/icon/icon.js", "app/base/base.js", "app/app.js"
    ];

    var injectOneByOne = function(scriptArr) {
        var script = scriptArr.splice(0, 1)[0];
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            file: script
        }, injectOneByOne.bind(null, scriptArr));
    };

    injectOneByOne(scripts);
});
```

As you can see there are 3 scripts in my app folder. The app.js bootstraps the app still.

```
(function() {
        var app = '<div class="extension-el"><div icon></div><div base></div></div>';
        var wrapper = '<div ng-non-bindable>' + app + '</div>';

        $('body').append(wrapper);
        angular.module('my-extension', ['columbus']);
        window.name = '';
        angular.bootstrap($('.extension-el')[0], ['my-extension']);
    }
})();
```

But when I load the extension only base directive is loading, icon is not. Can anyone point where I'm doing wrong?

EDITED:

icon.js (Not loading):

```
(function() {
    var columbus = angular.module('columbus', []);

    columbus.directive('icon', ['$sce', function(sce) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: sce.trustAsResourceUrl(chrome.extension.getURL('app/icon/icon.html')),
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.css({
                    width: '50px', height: '50px', position: 'fixed',
                    top: '80px', right: '300px', backgroundColor: '#2B76FF', zIndex: 2147483647
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

base.js (loading properly):

```
(function() {
    var columbus = angular.module('columbus', []);

    columbus.directive('base', ['$sce', function(sce) {
        return {
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: sce.trustAsResourceUrl(chrome.extension.getURL('app/base/base.html')),
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.css({
                    width: '300px', height: '100%', position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px', right: '0px', backgroundColor: '#2B76FF', zIndex: 2147483647
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Both directive files are added @wOxxOm

Comment: Well, try debugging it, for example add `debugger` in icon.js, reload the extension, open devtools (F12) on the webpage, run the extension and see what happens. Also, what's inside icon.html?

Comment: Actually I have done that already. icon.js itself is getting run but not its linker/link function. But not being able to find out the root cause for that

Comment: One more interesting thing, if I try to load icon only - it loads. Cannot understand why I'll be able to load only one directive at a time

Comment: Using different module for different directive fixes it @wOxxOm. Thanks for your co-operation :)